# how to subscribe an observable asynchronously from an array - angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I have an array contains IDs and I want to subscribe to an observable for each ID in the array in an orderly manner (make a request for id 1 then 2 ...).
I've tried foreach loop but the responses were unordered.
and tried to create a for loop and increase the index from the subscriber but the browser crushed(because tons of requests have been sent before the index changed)

my code:

```
const uniqueGroups=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
uniqueGroups.forEach(groupId => {
    this.magB1BaseService.getAttributeGroup(groupId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.AttributeGroups.push(data);
          this.AttributeGroupsCollapses[data.ID] = false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: try concatMap instead of forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concat operator to subscribe one by one.

```js
const uniqueGroups = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let obs: Array<Observable<any>> = [];
uniqueGroups.forEach( groupId => {
   obs.push(this.magB1BaseService.getAttributeGroup(groupId));
});
concat(...obs).subscribe( data => {
   this.AttributeGroups.push(data);
   this.AttributeGroupsCollapses[data.ID] = false;
});
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @WangJie your answer has one error `let obs Observable<any>=[] ` should be `let obs Observable<any>=[] `, and it works as well, thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to implement this is like below:

```
    const uniqueGroups = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    
    uniqueGroups.pipe(concatMap(groupId => (
      this.magB1BaseService.getAttributeGroup(groupId))
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.AttributeGroups.push(data);
        this.AttributeGroupsCollapses[data.ID] = false;
      })));
```

Comment: what if I don't know the array values? how can I make it like uniqueGroups in your code?

Comment: You can also use Observable.of(uniqueGroups);